# Own Big Float in C++

Tags: c++

I want to write my own variable "type" as a homework in C++. It should be an arbitrarily long float. I was thinking of structure like...

### Code:

```
class bigFloat
{
public:
    bigFloat(arguments);
    ~bigFloat();

private:
    std::vector<char> before; // numbers before decimal point
    std::vector<char> after; // numbers after decimal point
    int pos; // position of decimal point
};
```

Where if i have number like: 3.1415 
Before = '3'; after = '1415'; pos = 1;
If that makes sense to you... BUT assignment wants me to save some memory, which I don't because for every number I allocate about it is about 1 byte, which is too much I guess.

### Question:

How would you represent those arbitrarily long numbers? 
(Sorry for my bad english, I hope the post makes sense)

Comment: Use a vector of `uint`s in base 2^32.

Comment: @chris its just pregenerated with sublime, sorry...

Comment: 'position of decimal point' is after before.size() , so pos seems to be not needed

Comment: @SLaks can you clarify it a bit please? shoul i represent the numbers as a binary?

Comment: @tyrhus, Not binary, 2^32. Each 32-bit value is one digit.

Comment: @chris If i have understood right... if i have number like 4294967299 = 4294967296 (uint) + 3... i would store it like before[0] = 4294967296; before[1] = 3; ? And if so... how would I parse it from string? which can be infinity long?

Comment: No string can be infinitely long, because no computer has infinite storage. What you should say is that the string can be "arbitrarily long", which means that you are setting no fixed limit on how long it can be.

Comment: @TonyK yes, you are right! The thing is i should develop kind of calculator for arbitrarily long floats from arbitrarily long strings given.

Comment: You can cut the memory usage in half by using base-100 instead of base-10, and conversion to and from strings is still easy.

Comment: What are the operations you need to support? One usually designs the data-type based on the functions it need to allow.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks, so is it the way (in optimization memory) of using base 100 000 000 as the base the way (if i use `vector<unsigned int>`)?

Comment: @Andrei +, -, * division is not needed

Comment: @tyrhus: You can do that too, as long as your compiler has a 64-bit data type to handle the 32x32 multiplies

Comment: @BenVoigt okay, I will try it that way, I think I can use `unsigned long long` temporary variable to store multiplication, i guess

Comment: I would write an arbitrarily long integer before writing an arbitrarily long float.

Comment: For fun, check out fixed point math as well - what you have is very, very close to that.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to preserve memory, all that means is that you need to use memory as efficiently as possible. In other words, given the value you're storing, you shouldn't waste bytes.

Example:

1. 255 doesn't need 32 bits

I think your vector of chars is fine. If you're allowed to use a C++11 compiler, I'd probably change that to a vector of [uint8_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) and make sure when I'm storing the value that I can store a value from 0 to 255 in a vector of size 1.

However, that's not the end of it. From the sounds of it, what you're after is an arbitrary number of significant digits. However, for a true float representation, you also need to allocate storage for [the base and exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), after deciding what the base will be for your type. There is also the question of whether you want your exponent to be arbitrarily long too. Let's assume so.

So, I'd probably use something like this for members of your class:

```
//Assuming a base of 10.
static uint8_t const base = 10;
std::vector<uint8_t> digits_before_decimal;
std::vector<uint8_t> digits_after_decimal;
std::vector<uint8_t> exponent;
std::bitset<1> sign;
```

It is then a matter of implementing the various operators for your type and testing various scenarios to make sure your solution works.

If you really want to be thorough, you could use [a simple testing framework](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_Documentation) to make sure that problems you fix along the way, stay fixed.

In memory, it will essentially look like a binary representation of the number.

```
For example:
65535 will be: before_decimal =<0xff,0xff>, after_decimal vector is empty
255.255 will be: before_decimal =<0xff>, after_decimal=<0xff>
255255 will be: before_decimal =<0x03,0xe5,0x17>, after_decimal vector is empty
255255.0 will be: before_decimal =<0x03,0xe5,0x17>, after_decimal: <0>
```

As others have mentioned, you don't really need two vectors for before and after the decimal. However, I'm using two in my answer because it makes it easier to understand and you don't have to keep track of the decimal. The memory requirements of two vs one vector really aren't that different when you're dealing with a long string of digits.

I should also note that using an integer to record position of the decimal point limits your number of digits to 2 billion, which is not an arbitrarily long number.

UPDATE: If this actually is homework, I would check with whoever has given you the homework if you need to support any floating point special cases, the simplest of which would be  [NaNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#NaNs). There are [other special cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Special_values) too, but trying to implement all of them will very quickly turn this from a homework assignment into a thesis. Good luck :)

Comment: I question whether the exponent is necessary here, if es using two vectors already, why complicate it?

Comment: @carleeto thanks for your comment, it is a great idea of storing exponent and base but still my problem is, that i don't understand how it will look like in the memory... assume i have to store the number "123 456 789 987 654 321 . 001 002 003" how it will looks like in the vector? As I will work with base 10, I will store my number in the form such as 1. 23 456 789 987 654 321 001 002 003, so before[0] = 1; sign = 0; exponent = 17; after = ?

Comment: @tyrhus See my answer. It will look like this: mantissa = 1234567890087654321001002003, sign = '+', exponent = -9

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII exponent is necessary, but two vectors are not

Comment: @tyrhus: Answer updated. Yes, two vectors aren't necessary, but they make the problem easier to understand.

Comment: @carleeto Thanks for update! It's a slightly different approach to mine, because I was thinking of storing number like `255255` like: `<0x19,0x34,0x55>` so, in the way... `int<25, 52, 55>` to give you the idea (Because the char can "take" only 2 digits, since max 3-digit number 999 is not possible to store there). Of course, I wanted to store it in your way, but the problem is, how to parse string to such structure. `255255 ?= <0x03,0xe5,0x17>`

Comment: @carleeto Two vectors are not necessary because they make it harder to calculate, it has nothing to do with memory requirements. Simple example: what if you need to move decimal point one digit to the left? In both cases (two vectors vs one vector) you need to decrement exponent. In case of one vector you don't need to do anything else. In case of two vectors you also need to move one digit from "after" vector to "before" vector. That's all difference: two vectors force to make needless operation.

Comment: @kotlomoy Yes, there is more work involved using two vectors. However, it is easier to debug. Its pretty obvious from the question that there are difficulties with the concepts involved, which is why I'm keeping my solution simple. The order for a good solution is: (1) get it right (2) make it efficient.

Comment: @tyrhus You don't have to do it my way. If you feel more comfortable storing two digits at a time as a single entry in the vector, that's fine. Yes, it won't be as memory efficient, but it is a start and it is still better than 1 digit per vector entry. Remember, the important thing is getting your code to work properly first. Once it does, you can tweak it for better efficiency.

Comment: @carleeto no, no, your way is great and that's how it should be stored, it is really efficient that way as I can store really big numbers in just couple of `vector` "blocks". Now I need to think about parsing string into "powers" of some base and than figure out basic operations. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Is there any other information you're looking for before you accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use two separate vectors `before` and `after`. You need whole mantissa to make arithmetic operations.
2. Actually your `pos` is exponent. Name it accordingly. Exponent is signed btw.
3. You need sign of mantissa.
4. I recommend to store mantissa as rational fraction. You need two numbers: numerator and denominator. Then you can make division without round-off.
5. It's better to store numbers as ints with arbitrary length instead of arrays of digits.

---

PS. I made such calculator long time ago. To illustrate my answer, I give you declaration of class for number:

```
class CNumber
{
// ctors, methods....
   char cSign; // sign of mantissa
   CString strNumer; // numerator of mantissa
   CString strDenom; // denominator of mantissa
   char cExpSign; // sign of exponent
   CString strExp; // exponent
};
```

I used MFC. CString is standard string there.

Comment: Rationals are useful, but they don't qualify as floating-point.

Comment: Actually I made such calculator long time ago. I used rational fraction for mantissa and integer exponent. So, that was floating-point numbers. All worked fine.

Comment: Again, that's a workable system, but it is not what "floating-point" means.

Comment: @kotlomoy: The trouble with your suggestion is that the size of the numbers grows without limit as you perform more and more operations. Also, how do you represent pi?

Comment: @TonyK the size of the numbers grows in other solutions as well. What's problem with pi? I will represent it as numerator = 314159265359...(required quantity of significant digits), denominator = 1, exponent = (quantity_of_significant_digits - 1).

Comment: @BenVoigt floating-point basically means number which have mantissa and exponent. Mantissa contains significant numbers, exponent stores position of floating-point. My number meets all these requirements

Comment: @BenVoigt now I got what you mean. If denominator is not 1 than it's not floating-point indeed. So it's some sort of extension over floating-point. But I recommend this extension anyway